# Strange CSS rendering on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have simple CSS for styling a button: `<input class="button" type="submit" value="Join">`

```
...
.header__form-submit .button {
  background: #3371E3;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
...

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  ...
  .header__form-submit .button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

It renders fine on desktop, on any browser and on mobile preview in Chrome. However, when I open this on an iPhone the button has round corners.

Chrome preview:

[image]
iPhone either Chrome or Safari:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a problem with styling `<input />` on iOS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to go is:

`<button class="button" type="submit">Join</button>`

Answer (score 1):

disable default operating system styling

```
webkit-appearance: none;
```

Edit: add this to your css

```
input {
-webkit-border-radius:0; 
border-radius:0;
```

}

As well as the above line.

Comment: tried that and also without `-webkit`. did not help

Comment: you can do another thing style a div make that a button in javascript by using document.getElementById("buttonId").addEventListener("click",function(){ console.log("button clicked"); });

Comment: yes, definitely i could put an event handler on a `<div />`. you are correct about that. i am just wondering what is wrong with `<input />` and why BOTH `Safari` and `Chrome` would do this.